# Is there something I should be concerned about before port-forwarding my server?

Tags: portforwarding

I'm setting up my first server on a Raspberry Pi 4 but after reading some articles online I was wondering whether my server is ready to be open to the internet or not. I premise I'm just an individual who would like to publish some programming projects on a site that is accessible on a browser.
After some concerns I designed a PHP page which checks the client IP and returns a 403 header until i give that user the permission to access. Is it enough? Is it necessary?
And also, are there ports that are more safe to open than others?

Answer (score 0):

You "can" open ports 80 and/or 443 for displaying webpages - depending on SSL certificates

I do it myself (not for web hosting) and restrict the open ports to certain IPs - my friends (not smart enough to levy an attack ). Though IPs are likely to change every so often and your firewall will need updating.

---

It's a key thing to remember that anything is open to exploitation if it's not properly maintained/set up. Also displaying a 403 isn't a silver bullet.

Port 25 would give a user access to the files on your device if proper authorisation isn't set up. Opening ports 80 and 443 will give users access to webpages but makes your device/network exposed to DoS attacks or platform level attacks. If there's a known exploit for your version of PHP or your firewall/router or possibly the device itself then an attacker will exploit it.

Hosting providers have layers upon layers of security and are constantly updating devices throughout their network. Keeping your device and platform up to date will help - but it may be worth instead investing a little in a host (from about £4 a month).

There are loads more things I can touch on but will leave it at that for now

**Edit after comment:**

> my website is just a little project i mean who could casually target it?

Strictly speaking, anyone. "Who would want to?" Again, anyone. Sure you're a small target that wouldn't provide any useful data. But your device, once hacked, can be used as a DoS zombie or as a crypto-miner and you probably wouldn't even realise.

> And also can't I use whatever port like 6969 or 45688?

Yes, strictly speaking, you can. You could tell your device to listen on that port and reply with the website data. To do this you would also need to provide the port number on the end of the URL in the format `www.example.com:6969`. Though, again, this isn't a silver bullet. Most security issues aren't with port-forwarding but with poor management/security and bugs in the components themselves. All a port forwarder is doing is saying "oh, device X wants data on this port... here you go".

Another point is, data sent on "Well-known ports" (1-1023) tend to have their headers checked for irregularities by the firewall - which can dispose of any irregular packets. By using a custom port the firewall doesn't really know what to expect, so it sends it anyway. Also, steer away from "Private ports" (49152-65535) these are used as source ports, not destination ports.

Comment: I partially get what you're telling me but my website is just a little project i mean who could casually target it? And also can't I use whatever port like 6969 or 45688?

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm learning a lot from your answers. The only thing I don't get is how I can make my best to secure - as possibile - my server without spending money.

Comment: There's no guarantee. But some best steps are to keep everything up to date with the latest security fixes and manage IP access at a firewall level rather than a site level. If they get a response from your site then they can access your site and possibly elevate privileges to the device itself.